# htaccess redirect from domain.com/index.php?page=about to domain.com/about

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I've upgraded an old website and wanted to redirect all the old pages to the new ones. the old website used the index page and a query string to server the relevant content.

here is the new htaccess file. the problem in question is getting the redirect to work. also if you can steamline this file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#if its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#and it has a trailing slash then redirect to URL without slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#this removes php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

# stops you accessing url with.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^.?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php(/.+)?$ /$1%{PATH_INFO} [R=301]

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /news?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

Redirect 301 index?page=about http://domain.co.uk/about

ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.co.uk/404
```

Answer (score 0):

The apropiate rule to redirect domain.com/index.php?page=about to domain.com/about is the following

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [C]
RewriteRule page=(.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```